# How can I reformat a two-dimensional array in VBA to have two "0" values between each item?

Tags: arrays, vba

I'll preface this by saying I'm very new to VBA, effectively restarted today after not having used it since economics at uni.

I have created a two-dimensional array `Answers()` that contains the answers from a number of respondents (`Resp`) to a number of questions (`Ques`).

Here's an example of the first line in the array:

```
[3,3,3,2,1,2,2,3,1,3,1,2]
```

I need to format this into a new array with two `0` values between each value in the original array, and at the end, so that the first line ends up like this:

```
[3,0,0,3,0,0,3,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0,3,0,0,1,0,0,3,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0]
```

I have searched around for similar examples and found something close, but I can't figure out how to make it read the correct value from the original array in each step of the for loop:

```
Dim Resp As Integer
Dim Ques As Integer
Resp = 200
Ques = 12

Dim Answers() As Integer
ReDim Answers(1 to Resp, 1 to Ques) As Integer

Dim lastIndex As Integer
lastIndex = Ques * 3

Dim Answers_Long() As Integer
ReDim Answers_Long(1 To Resp, 1 To lastIndex) As Integer

For r = 1 To Resp
    For i = 1 To lastIndex Step 3
        Answers_Long(r, i) = Answers(r, CInt(i / 3))
        Answers_Long(r, i + 1) = 0
        Answers_Long(r, i + 2) = 0
    Next i
Next r
```

If you have any tips for how I can change the line:

```
Answers_Long(r, i) = Answers(r, CInt(i / 3))
```

to correctly read the data from `Answers()` it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think the problem have been solved by using the Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `For i = 1 To lastIndex Step 3`, the variable `i` starts at 1 and increments by 3 on each iteration of the loop.  That is, it takes the values 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, etc.

These values are *not* divisible by 3 (since the sequence starts at 1 instead of 0), so when you divide `i` by 3, you end up with fractional values like 0.3333, 1.3333, 2.3333, 3.3333, etc.

Fortunately, `CInt()` does round such fractional numbers to the nearest integer, so that `CInt(i / 3)` will take the values 0, 1, 2, 3, etc.  However, you've still got a problem: Since you declared the `Answers()` array to use 1-based indexing (with `1 to Ques`), the index of the first element of each row is not 0, but 1.

Thus, you will need to add 1 to the output of `CInt()`  to actually get the right index.  (This is one of those situations where 0-based array indexing would actually result in simpler code.)

---

The least change you could make to your existing code to get it working would be:

```
Answers_Long(r, i) = Answers(r, 1 + CInt(i / 3))
```

Alternatively, you could also avoid the need to round the result of the division using:

```
Answers_Long(r, i) = Answers(r, 1 + CInt((i - 1) / 3))
```

in which case you should be able to get rid of the `CInt()` entirely:

```
Answers_Long(r, i) = Answers(r, 1 + (i - 1) / 3)
```

Of course, another option would be to rewrite your code entirely to use 0-based array indexing, in which case it would look something like this:

```
Dim Answers() As Integer
ReDim Answers(0 to Resp-1, 0 to Ques-1) As Integer

Dim TripleQues As Integer
TripleQues = Ques * 3

Dim Answers_Long() As Integer
ReDim Answers_Long(0 to Resp-1, 0 to TripleQues-1) As Integer

For r = 0 To Resp - 1
    For i = 0 To TripleQues - 3 Step 3
        Answers_Long(r, i) = Answers(r, i / 3)
        Answers_Long(r, i + 1) = 0
        Answers_Long(r, i + 2) = 0
    Next i
Next r
```